# Unexpected behavior with CORS on .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, cors, .net-core-3.1

I have added the following to my service configuration.

```
services.AddCors(options 
    => options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder 
        => builder
            //.AllowAnyHeader()
            .WithHeaders("header-that-nobody-knows")
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:44304")));
```

My expectation was that the calls would bounce (as I don't add *header-that-nobody-knows* to my headers). However, the request is carried out just as if `AllowAnyHeader()` was set.

Manipulating the port, domain or protocol in `WithOrigins()` produces the expected result, so the config seems to be wired up properly. I suspect it's a special case somehow because I'm getting unexpected behavior with `WithMetod()` when it comes to *GET* and *POST* (while other methods are blocked/allowed depending on the paramers passed).

Checking [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0) gave nothing I recon as explanation.

I doubt that it matters but for completeness sake, here's the Angular code invoking the call.

```
let url = "https://localhost:44301/security/corstest?input=blobb";
this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe(
  next => console.log("next", next),
  err => console.warn("err", err));
```

The action method looks as below.

```
[HttpGet("corstest")]
public IActionResult CorsTest([FromQuery] string input)
{
    return Ok(new { data = input + " indeed..." });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to send a request to a cross-origin URL with a "non-standard" header,
the browser will perform a preflight `OPTIONS` request with the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header that contains the non-standard headers.

```
OPTIONS /corstest

Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: header-that-nobody-knows
Origin: https://my.api
```

ASP.NET Core inspects this value and checks if the CORS policy has `AllowAnyHeader` or if it explicitly allows it with `.WithHeaders`, if not it will issue a non-200 response and the browser will refuse to send the actual request.

So, not adding `header-that-nobody-knows` to request headers doesn't mean ASP.NET Core will refuse to serve the request, it means if you set `header-that-nobody-knows` header in a cross-origin request, it *will* allow it instead of issuing a non-200 response (assuming you allowed it with `WithHeaders` or `AllowAllHeaders`)

So in a nutshell:

- You have to allow some/all origins + some/all headers at minimum for a CORS policy to take effect.
- Browser expects both `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the preflight request to match the main request.
- You can only send a subset (which includes 0) of the allowed headers.

### References

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests

Comment: I'm a bit confused, possibly to a typo or linguistic bump with too many negations. Let me digest it. Case #1: I set *htnk* in my request and have allowing header *htnk* on the server. Result #1: the request is served. Case #2: I set **not** *htnk* in my request but have it allowed on the server. Result #2: the request is also served? I would expect that **only** set header to whatever the server allows would work (excluding the allow-all case for simplicity). What's the point of setting allow-this-or-that if everything is served anyway?!

Comment: Please note that I'm sending my request **without** said custom header, as shown in the sample. It's just simple, plain GET with no bells attached. Are you saying that it's sufficient to be from the allowed origin to pass given the setup above? I thought it was allow-if-origin-**and**-if-headers were correct.

Comment: Case 1: request is served. Case 2: served as well. If you don't set any headers in the CORS policy, it [effectively allows all headers](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ac3a403cb3e496841e76d367d41519f8273cebe8/src/Middleware/CORS/src/Infrastructure/CorsPolicy.cs#L31-L42) (if I interpreted the code right).

Comment: _I would expect that only set header to whatever the server allows would work_ True. If you allow only `asd` header, and send `xyz` header, the request wouldn't be served.

Comment: Assume you allow origin `x` and headers `a`, `b`, `c`.  **Case 1**: the request comes from origin `y` -> not served. **Case 2**: origin `x`, headers `a` -> served. **Case 3**: origin x, headers `a`, `b`, and `m` -> not served. **Case 4**: origin `x` with headers `a`, `b`, `c` -> served.

Comment: Just checked: you need to set both origins and headers (either with `AllowAllHeaders` or `WithHeaders`) of a policy. If you only set origins, you get `CORS Missing Allow Header` error. So my comment above about the effective behaviour is **incorrect**.

Comment: So in a nutshell: You have to allow some/all origins + some/all headers at minimum for a CORS policy to take effect. Browser expects both `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the preflight request to match the main request. You can send a subset (which includes 0) of the allowed headers.

Comment: What about **case 5**: request from origin *x* headers *m* (i.e. no *a*, *b* nor *c*). I would expect that **not** to be served. But it seems to be served. The allowance of all headers is commented out so only requests with the said headers are going through. Yet, my call seems to be served despite lacking that header (and it's the only one set for CORS). Isn't that weird? Can you confirm that you can reproduce that?

Comment: That doesn't work for me. It depends on what `m` actually is. If that's a "standard" header, it's not subject to CORS restrictions. If I, for example, allow only `Authorization` header and send something else `Authorization1`, the request gets blocked.

Comment: Try this: `app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().WithHeaders("M"));` then send this request from the browser console: `fetch('https://localhost:$port', {headers: {MM: '123'}})`. The request is blocked. `fetch('https://localhost:5001', {headers: {Accept: '123'}})` works, because `Accept` is a "standard" header. (`M` already works)